# FFMPEG stream .mpg to windows pipe and display video in C#

Tags: c#, ffmpeg

i've got problem with streaming mpg video to windows pipe. I wang decode video with command ffmpeg.exe to windows pipe and connect to that pipe with c# and display video on winform. I've tried many commands but none of them worked.

FFmpeg command:

ffmpeg -i Day Flight.mpg -f image2pipe pipe:1 > //./pipe/ffpipe

C# code:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.Threading;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{

public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String readLine_;
    private void readThread()
    {

        while (true)
        {
            readLine_ = reader_.ReadLine();
            if (readLine_ != null)
            {

                byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(readLine_);
                //Console.WriteLine(readLine_);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
                // Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(ms);
                Image im = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(bytes));
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("empty string");

            //



        }
    }
    private NamedPipeServerStream server_;
    StreamReader reader_;


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        server_ = new NamedPipeServerStream("ffpipe", PipeDirection.In, 1, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte);
        server_.WaitForConnection();
        reader_ = new StreamReader(server_);
        Thread t = new Thread(readThread);
        t.Start();


    }


    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();
}
```

}

I can't get image in C#, my program crashes in line
Image im = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(bytes));

And I don't know where I make a mistake - in ffmpeg piping or in C# program
https://image.ibb.co/eGDymp/Przechwytywanie.png
https://image.ibb.co/hWpM6p/Przechwytywanie.png

Example video:
http://samples.ffmpeg.org/MPEG2/mpegts-klv/Day%20Flight.mpg

Comment: What _exactly_ doesn't work? Where is your _specific_ and _isolated_ issue? Please read the [ask] topics to get informed what questions can be answered here, on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I can't get image in C#, my program crashes in line
Image im = (Bitmap)((new ImageConverter()).ConvertFrom(bytes));
And I don't know where I make a mistake - in ffmpeg piping or in C# program

Comment: Please provide both exception type and message that lead to crash. By the way, getting raw bytes from a stream using a `StreamReader` is wrong. Use the `NamedPipeServerStream.Read` method instead.

Comment: Exeption type: System.ArgumentExeption
Exeption message: Incorrect parametr